# What is end-of-line for python's csv.reader?

Tags: python, csv

Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) specifies:

> The reader is hard-coded to recognise either '\r' or '\n' as end-of-line, and ignores lineterminator. This behavior may change in the future.

I wrote a simple program

#### step 1

```
with open('test.csv','wb') as f:
    f.write(b'hello\r\rworld\n!')
```

#### step 2

```
import csv

with open('test.csv','r',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in r:
        print(row)
```

Output of `step 2`:

```
['hello']
[]
['world']
['!']
```

If I change `step 1` to :

```
import csv

with open('test.csv','wb') as f:
    f.write(b'hello\r\nworld\n!')
```

Output:

```
['hello']
['world']
['!']
```

**My question is why the empty list `[]` disappeared in this case?**

If I am correct then in `step 2` `csv.reader` encountered first `\r` and returned what it had read until then, but when it encountered second `\r` immediately after first, it had not read anything and hence returned empty list.

But why this doesn't happen in second case if `\n` is also end-of-line for `csv.reader`?

Comment: `'test.txt'` is not a valid CSV file, so all bets are off.

Comment: @martineau okay, I changed it, still same output...

Comment: The file's extension isn't what I meant — it doesn't matter. It's the fact that you're writing the test file in binary mode and not giving it the proper end-of-line characters (which are by default the `\r\n` (CRLF) pair). This is defined in the CSV format spec [RFC4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180.html) which is what the `csv` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) says it supports.

Comment: ... While you *can* change it to something else via the [`csv.Dialect.lineterminator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) option when *writing* a file, it doesn't affect the reading of them. Even if it did, your file appears to be mixture of two different types…so like the old computer adage says: "Garbage in, garbage out."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the built-in `write` function.

If you look at your files, you will already see the difference.
The output file when using `b'hello\r\rworld\n!'` contains:

```
hello

world
!
```

And when you use `b'hello\r\nworld\n!'`, then this produces this file content:

```
hello
world
!
```

Therefore, it has nothing to do with the CSV reader.

Back to your issue: My **guess** is that `\r\r` is interpreted individually when writing `b'hello\r\rworld\n!'` to the file. On the other hand, the combination `\r\n` is interpreted as one control character.

My assumption is based on:

> A manner of interpreting text streams in which all of the following are recognized as ending a line: the Unix end-of-line convention `'\n'`, the Windows convention `'\r\n'`, and the old Macintosh convention `'\r'`. See PEP 278 and PEP 3116, as well as `bytes.splitlines()` for an additional use.

from https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines

Trying out [`bytes.splitlines()`](http://%20https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.splitlines):

```py
result = b'halifax\ndigby\n\nzuerich\rbern\r\rlugano\r\nlausanne'.splitlines()
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

Results in:

```
b'halifax'
b'digby'
b''
b'zuerich'
b'bern'
b''
b'lugano'
b'lausanne'
```

And, if you swap `\r\n` to `\n\r`, which is not a recognized as a line ending, then it will write two new lines. That said `b'hello\n\rworld\n!'` will result in this file content:

```
hello

world
!
```

I hope that helps. Cheers!

See also:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0093876328afa330224c9d887c18dee0b3117852/Modules/_io/fileio.c

Comment: Yes, it is the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a documentation bug. CR by itself is a fairly unusual end-of-line marker (i think pre-unix MacOS used it, as well as the venerable Swedish ABC80 that I grew up with :-) ), but CR+LF is very common, so it would make sense for csv.reader to interpret a CR+LF sequence as a single end-of-line.

Comment: if  `CR` is not end-of-line marker(here), then why `csv.reader` returns empty list in step 2?

Comment: My guess would be that CR by itself counts as EOL, as does LF by itself, but CR+LF counts as just one EOL, not two.